# sed or awk to match part of strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have looked through SO and found many things similar, but this is less complicated I just cant seem to quite get there...
I am working on csv text manipulation to automate tasks. 
I need to replace Communication, with Communication - articulating one's self;
but when the string Sports Communication, appears I dont want that changed. I think its close to

```
sed -i.bak "s/[Sports]! Communication,/Communication - articulating one\'s self;/g" out.csv
```

I would be fine with an awk solution but more familiar with sed its in a bash file so really any common command line solution would be great

```
unassigned,2.5,"Sports Communication,","The Campus...lots of other data...will be required.",Communication,Collaboration,Brand
```

Communication can be switched with Collaboration or Brand or not be there

Comment: Can you give us how the lines look like i.e. in separate lines (or) comma separated

Comment: show the input fragment

Comment: added csv fragment

Comment: Inian thanks so much. I have some ugly solutions that are 99% working I am mostly refactoring this will make it much better. I was Marking all the Sports Communcation, with a sequence to avoid changing then changing back at the end, but it ran into other issues.

Comment: sed doesn't understand fields so you cannot use sed robustly for this. Awk does but you need GNU awk for `FPAT` to handle CSV [mostly] robustly. Other tools have even more robust CSV parsers available. Since you've already selected an answer, though, it's unlikely you'll get the right one now. Ask another question if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Awk` statement like this,

```
awk -F\, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(match($i,/^Communication$/)) {gsub(/^Communication$/,"Communication - articulating one\047s self;",$i);} }}1' file
```

which produces an output as below for your input file

```
unassigned 2.5 "Sports Communication " "The Campus...lots of other data...will be required." Communication - articulating one's self; Collaboration Brand
```

In latest GNU Awk (since [4.1.0 released](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.awk/browse_thread/thread/40ce7554f025c382)), it has the option of ["inplace" file editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html):

> [...] The "inplace" extension, built using the new facility, can be used to simulate the GNU "`sed -i`" feature. [...]

and to keep a backup of the file with an extension a needed

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -F\, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(match($i,/^Communication$/)) {gsub(/^Communication$/,"Communication - articulating one\047s self;",$i);} }}1' file
```

(or) for an older version, just use a temporary file and swap it back,

```
awk -F\, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if(match($i,/^Communication$/)) {gsub(/^Communication$/,"Communication - articulating one\047s self;",$i);} }}1' file > temp && mv temp > file
```

One-level of simplification based on the one-and-the-only Ed Morton's comments below to directly do the substitution and avoid an un-necessary `match()`,

```
awk -F\, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sub(/^Communication$/,"Communication - articulating one\047s self;",$i);} }1' file
```

Comment: Why `match($i,/^Communication$/)` instead of `$i=="Communication"`? Why search for it THEN change it instead of just trying to change it? Why gsub() instead of sub() for 1 possible replacement? Finally - this solution cannot work robustly since strings within fields can contain commas (see the posted sample input), you'd need FPAT for an awk-based solution.

Comment: @EdMorton: Appreciate your valuable comments as usual, I guess I need to make a lot of changes. Am lost on the `FPAT` solution. Perhaps you could post one yourself

Comment: I typically just skip it when an answer has already been selected since the OP has presumably moved on already and anyone looking in future will just focus on the accepted answer so it's kinda wasted effort posting a solution at that point. Basically, though, you need to use `FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` instead of `FS=","` for parsing CSV files with awk and that only works in GNU awk. That's so `a,"b,c",d` is parsed as 3 fields `<a>`, `<"b,c">`, and `<d>` instead of 4 `<a>`, `<"b>`, `<c">`, and `<d>`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content for more info.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed! Will explore more on `FPAT` starting today, btw updated all your comments except the former

Comment: wrt FPAT just a heads up there was a bug introduced in gawk 4.1.4 related to handling empty fields (see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2017-04/msg00000.html) so if you're using that then you need to do `oFPAT=FPAT; FPAT=""; FPAT=oFPAT` at the start of processing each record. If you're on an older gawk then you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed "s/\(,Communication\),/\1 - articulating one's self;,/g" file
```

***awk*** approach:

```
awk -F',' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/^Communication/)
    {gsub("Communication","Communication - articulating one\047s self;",$i);} }}1' file
```